# increase to a peak of

Tags: word-choice

Is it ok to use "increased to a peak" instead of "reached a peak" with regard to the following sentence?

"Viewing figures for the 9:30 news increased to a peak of 3.8 million in May"

Answer (score 5):

*Increased to a peak of* is grammatically correct but the use of *increased* may cause the reader to wonder if it decreased after it reached a peak, or if it stayed at that level.

*Reached a peak of* is more usual. *Peaked at* is also good.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and yes. Actually It happened the way you said. From May onwards, the figure for 9:30 news plummeted, hitting a low-point of 1.1 million.